# Excel how to dynamically update cell column when dragging column down?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

```
=IF(ISBLANK(OFFSET('IC FX Elim Worksheet'!**BN13**,0,2)),"0",(SUMPRODUCT(--('IC FX Elim Worksheet'!$5:$5='Summary Unrealized FX'!$A44), --('IC FX Elim Worksheet'!$6:$6="USD"), 'IC FX Elim Worksheet'!$12:$12)-SUMPRODUCT(--('IC FX Elim Worksheet'!$5:$5='Summary Unrealized FX'!$A43), --('IC FX Elim Worksheet'!$6:$6="USD"), 'IC FX Elim Worksheet'!$12:$12)))
```

I'm trying to use the offset function to make BN13 move two columns over each time the column in dragged down.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: One way is to copy the formulas horizontally and then paste with Transpose

Answer (score 0):

So I have a couple of options for you depending on what exactly it is you want.

So you say you want the BN13 to move two columns over each time it is dragged down a row. If you want that but you want the 13 to remain the same then try this:

```
=OFFSET(INDIRECT("R13C"&66+((ROW()-ROW($A$2))*2),FALSE),0,2)
```

Just change the $A$2 to the first cell you input the formula in.

If you want the 13 to still adjust by one each time you drag down then try this:

```
=OFFSET(INDIRECT("R"&13+(ROW()-ROW($A$2))&"C"&66+((ROW()-ROW($A$2))*2),FALSE),0,2)
```

Again change the $A$2 to the first cell you input the formula in.

The idea behind this was changing the cell reference to what is called the R1C1 style using the indirect formula. This style uses numbers for both the row and columns this allows us to do math on the column and row parts of a cell reference to change them in any way we see fit.